# How do you search inside of child tables using CakeDC search?

Tags: cakephp, search, cakedc

I have search working fine for the parent model, but I have no idea how to get child models/tables included in the Select portion of the query.

Using Cake 2.3.8

This article ([how to use cakedc/search plugin for searching across 3 different tables with 1 search bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17907146/how-to-use-cakedc-search-plugin-for-searching-across-3-different-tables-with-1-s)) seems like the closest answer, but I'm new to cake and don't quite understand @mark's concise answer.

Any help would be much appreciated, 
Thanks!

Comment: what is exactly the relationship between your Models? Can you make an example?

Comment: Thanks @arilia, I have a Books Model that has many Authors and many Awards.  In my search, I would like to use one search bar.  If a visitor searches using the title as the search term, it is fine since that data is in the Books table.  However, I would also like to be able to search by the Author's name, and return all books by that author, but it is not working since I can't get cakeDC search to search the child models (authors and awards).

Answer (score 0):

Let me shorten the example from the readme.md for you, it should become obvious:

```
class Article extends AppModel {
    public $actsAs = array('Search.Searchable');
    public $belongsTo = array('User');
    public $filterArgs = array(
        'title' => array('type' => 'like'),
        'username' => array('type' => 'like', 'field' => array(
            'User.username', 'UserInfo.first_name')),
    );
```

Notice the `Model.field` notation for the `username` filter.